# create a pl/sql procedure to change the staus of the video database table

Tags: plsql

**My question**

Create a procedure called `video_return` to change the rental status for that returned copy. When the copy is successfully checked in, 
you need to update the corresponding rows (records) in the `VIDEO_RENTAL_RECORD` and `VIDEO_COPY` tables.

**The following are the special cases:**

The value

- of `p_video_copy_id` does not exist in the corresponding column of
  the `VIDEO_COPY` table.
- The status of that copy is not “R” (STATUS !=
  'R').
- The value of `p_video_return_date` is greater than the current date.

I have written the code but I am not sure if this code is correct or not. Please, can anyone help me out with the code? Thank you so much.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE video_return(
    p_video_copy_id NUMBER,
    p_video_return_date DATE
) AS

    video_copy_id number;
    video_return_date date;
    v_count number;

begin

    select count(*) into v_count
      from video
      WHERE video_copy_id = p_video_copy_id;

    if p_video_copy_id != video_copy_id then
        Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE('Video number ' || p_video_copy_id || ' not found.');
    end if;

    if p_video_copy_id = video_copy_id then
        update video 
          set p_status = 'IN'
          where p_video_copy_id = video_copy_id;

        IF p_video_return_date > SYSDATE THEN

            update video_rental_record
              set p_video_return_date = SYSDATE
              where p_video_copy_id = video_copy_id
                AND p_video_return_date IS NULL;

            Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE('Video successfully returned and available for rental.');

        END IF;

    END IF;

END IF ;
END;
```

Comment: Did you test your code?

Comment: yes i did but its not working its giving an error Error(18,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  Error(19,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "P_STATUS": invalid identifier

Comment: Please try to write you code in a readable format and it is easy to debug too.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE video_return
(
  p_video_copy_id NUMBER,
  p_video_return_date DATE
)
as
  video_copy_id number;
  video_return_date date;
  v_count number;
begin
  select count(*) into v_count from video
    WHERE video_copy_id = p_video_copy_id;
  if p_video_copy_id != video_copy_id then
    Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE('Video number ' || p_video_copy_id || ' not found.');
  end if;
  if p_video_copy_id = video_copy_id then
    update video set p_status = 'IN'
      where p_video_copy_id = video_copy_id;
  end if; -- add end if here
  IF p_video_return_date > SYSDATE THEN
    update video_rental_record set p_video_return_date = SYSDATE
      where p_video_copy_id = video_copy_id AND p_video_return_date IS NULL;
    Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE('Video successfully returned and available for rental.');
  END IF;
--END IF;
--END IF ;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of things conceptually missing here in your code. You have not initialized "video_copy_id" variable so it will be always NULL and NULL cant be compared with anything. So basically you either need to initialize the variable so change the conditions. Hope below snippet helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE video_return(
    p_video_copy_id     NUMBER,
    p_video_return_date DATE )
AS
  video_copy_id     NUMBER; --Not initialized always NULL
  video_return_date DATE;
  v_count           NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM video WHERE video_copy_id = p_video_copy_id;
  IF p_video_copy_id != nvl(video_copy_id,'some value') THEN --Cant compare anything with null
    Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE('Video number ' || p_video_copy_id || ' not found.');
  END IF;
  IF p_video_copy_id = video_copy_id THEN
    UPDATE video SET p_status = 'IN' WHERE p_video_copy_id = nvl(video_copy_id,'some value'); --Never satisfied
    IF p_video_return_date > SYSDATE THEN
      UPDATE video_rental_record
      SET p_video_return_date  = SYSDATE
      WHERE p_video_copy_id    = nvl(video_copy_id,'some value') --Never satisfied
      AND p_video_return_date IS NULL;
      Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE('Video successfully returned and available for rental.');
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```